# Why even on using float left, adding text will make it falls below the image?

Tags: html, css

[image]

**I have used the float-left property to wrap the text around the image. But on adding more text, it is appearing below the image, instead of right.**

In the class chess, I have used float property and set it to left.

The CSS I used.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Cambo', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
    font-size: 5.625rem;
    color: #66BFBF;
}

h2 {
    color: #66BFBF;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h3 {    
    color: #66BFBF;
}

.top-container {
    background-color: #E4F9F5;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    ;
}

.pro {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.top-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 50px;
}

.bottom-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 300px;
}

.chess {
    width:25%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.pc-games {
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.skill-row {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto 100px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 2;
}
```

Please help me out..................................

---

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cambo&family=Montserrat:ital@1&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <img class="top-cloud" src="https://i.ibb.co/jGjL96C/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <h1>I'm Shivam.</h1>
    <h2>a <span class="pro">pro</span>grammar.</h2>
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="https://i.ibb.co/jGjL96C/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hcwP6Vx/mountain.png" alt="cloud-img">
  </div>

  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="images/my.png" alt="my-img">
      <h2>Hello.</h2>
      <p>I am a programmer and web developer.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="skills">
      <h2>My Skills.</h2>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img class="chess" src="https://i.ibb.co/jLd0jzv/chess.png" alt="chess-img">
        <h3 class="footer-link">Chess</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit repellat qufsfdsdfsfggesgggsdgrsdggdsge nemo cupiditate facilis ullam lsdam sunt? Error necessitatibus doloremque ab atque! Quas optio ..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="skill-row">
        <img class="pc-games" src="https://i.ibb.co/1GqMbPP/pcgames.webp" alt="pc-games-img">
        <h3 class="footer-link">PC Games</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto culpa eveniet facere veritatis iste, dolore quos quae ipsa deserunt et quo dolores quia dolorum similique laboriosam undbcaecati. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact-me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet. Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p>
      <a class="btn" href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">CONTACT ME</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottom-container">
    <p class="footer-link">© XYZ.</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That is the expected behavior of `float`. If you don't want that, then don't use `float`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have Added bootstrap CDN Link sna used bootstrap classes to arrange the image and text side by side

```css
 body {
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Cambo', serif;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
        font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
        font-size: 5.625rem;
        color: #66BFBF;
    }

    h2 {
        color: #66BFBF;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    h3 {
        color: #66BFBF;
    }

    .top-container {
        background-color: #E4F9F5;
        position: relative;
    }

    .pro {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .top-cloud {
        position: absolute;
        right: 300px;
        top: 50px;
    }

    .bottom-cloud {
        position: absolute;
        left: 300px;
        bottom: 300px;
    }

    .chess {
        width: 50%;
        /* float: left; */

    }

    .pc-games {
        width: 50%;
        /* float: left; */

    }

    /* .skill-row {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 100px auto 100px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 2;
    } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cambo&family=Montserrat:ital@1&family=Sacramento&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid top-container">
        <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
        <h1>I'm Shivam.</h1>
        <h2>a <span class="pro">pro</span>grammar.</h2>
        <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
        <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="cloud-img">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="profile">
            <img src="images/my.png" alt="my-img">
            <h2>Hello.</h2>
            <p>I am a programmer and web developer.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="skills">
            <h2>My Skills.</h2>
            <div class="row skill-row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="chess" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586165368502-1bad197a6461?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=958&q=80" alt="chess-img" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3>Chess</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit repellat
                        qufsfdsdfsfggesgggsdgrsdggdsge nemo cupiditate facilis ullam lsdam sunt? Error necessitatibus
                        doloremque ab atque! Quas optio
                        ..
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row skill-row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="pc-games" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616588589676-62b3bd4ff6d2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1032&q=80" alt="pc-games-img" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3>PC Games</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto culpa eveniet facere veritatis
                        iste,
                        dolore quos quae ipsa deserunt et quo dolores quia dolorum similique laboriosam undbcaecati.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact-me">
        <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet. Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p>
        <a class="btn" href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">CONTACT ME</a>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="bottom-container">
        <p class="footer-link">© XYZ.</p>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```